# How to break shared_ptr cyclic reference using weak_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++03

I have read that weak_pointers can be used to break cyclic references.

Consider the following example of a cyclic reference

```
struct A
{
boost::shared_ptr<A> shrd_ptr;
};


boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_A(boost::make_shared<A>());
boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_b(boost::make_shared<A>());
ptr_A->shrd_ptr = ptr_b;
ptr_b->shrd_ptr = ptr_A;
```

Now above is a case of cyclic reference and I wanted to know how I can break 
the cyclic reference above by using `weak_ptr` ?

Update : 
Based on suggestion received I came up with the following :

```
struct A
{
  boost::weak_ptr<A> wk_ptr;
};

    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_A (boost::make_shared<A>());
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_B (boost::make_shared<A>());
    ptr_A->wk_ptr = ptr_B;
    ptr_B->wk_ptr = ptr_A;
```

Will this be the correct approach ?

Comment: Change `A::shrd_ptr` to `boost::weak_ptr` and hold a `shared_ptr` somewhere else.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The classic example of cyclic references is where you have two classes `A` and `B` where `A` has a reference to `B` which has a reference to `A`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct B;
struct A {
  std::shared_ptr<B> b;  
  ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

struct B {
  std::shared_ptr<A> a;
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }  
};

void useAnB() {
  auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
  auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
  a->b = b;
  b->a = a;
}

int main() {
   useAnB();
   std::cout << "Finished using A and B\n";
}
```

If both references are `shared_ptr` then that says `A` has ownership of `B` and `B` has ownership of `A`, which should ring alarm bells. In other words, `A` keeps `B` alive and `B` keeps `A` alive.

In this example the instances `a` and `b` are only used in the `useAnB()` function so we would like them to be destroyed when the function ends but as we can see when we run the program the destructors are not called.

The solution is to decide who owns who. Lets say `A` owns `B` but `B` does not own `A` then we replace the reference to `A` in `B` with a `weak_ptr` like so:

```
struct B {
  std::weak_ptr<A> a;
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }  
};
```

Then if we run the program we see that `a` and `b` are destroyed as we expect.

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JKW9GyfhvYOtvKfV)</kbd>

**Edit:** In your case,  the approach you suggested looks perfectly valid. Take ownership away from `A` and something else owns the `A`s.

Comment: will the problem(cyclic reference) remain if we later create shared_ptr from a.lock()?

Comment: @Explorer_N Providing `B` doesn't hold on to a `shared_ptr` created from `a.lock()` permanently then it is OK. [Here is an expanded version of the live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mdIkQ3QbFhaskdro) that includes an example of using `a.lock()`.

Comment: Chris,How it is , creating shared_ptr will increase the reference count of the managed object was it? i have also changed the `auto sa = a.lock();` to `static shared_ptr<A> sa;`, yet it works well.....i am wondering.

Comment: @Explorer_N Yes, `auto sa = a.lock()` will increase the reference count of `a` but the reference count will decrease again when `sa` goes out-of-scope so that is fine.

Comment: struct B {
  std::weak_ptr<A> a;
  std::shared_ptr<A> sa;
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }
  void doSomethingWithA() {
      sa = a.lock();
     if (!sa)
         return;
     std::cout << "a.value: " << sa->value << "\n";
  }
};     this doesn't break the cyclic reference

Comment: the code you pasted in wand box has   'auto sa = a.lock();' the shared_ptr inside the function but if we declare shared_ptr in struct the problem wasn't solved

Comment: @Explorer_N Indeed, as I said, If`B` holds on to the `shared_ptr` then you have a cyclic reference.